# what is the meaning of -1 in the end of random()

Tags: python

class Food:

```
def __init__(self):
    
    x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE)-1) *  SPACE_SIZE  
    y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE
```

this is a part of Game Snake in python

Comment: `randint` takes two parameters, start and stop, `0` is the start and `(GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE)-1` is the stop. Why they calculated stop this way would just be guessing.

Comment: simply use `print()` to see value `(GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE)-1` and think what would be happend if you would use `(GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE)` - probably it would draw snake outside window (so it will be not visible)  because `randint(start, end)` may return value `end` as opposed to functions `randrange(start, end)` which returns `end-1`

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `range(0, end)` or `randrange(0, end)` give values `0 ... end-1`
but `randint(0, end)` gives values `0 ... end` so you need `end-1` to get only `0 ... end-1`.

And object `Food` may need `end-1` to put object inside window.
With `end` it would put object outside window and you wouldn't see it (and you couldn't get it)